# Timer in Python runs only for x seconds and then stops

Tags: python, multithreading

I am getting the information for weather every X seconds but it seems that after the three threads have executed the Timer just stops and the program as well. The problem is that this was working two days ago and I am not sure if anything has been modified as I can't see a any difference, however it used to run for as long as the program was kept running. Now it runs 3 times and stops.

```
import requests
import json
import threading
import time
from threading import Thread

def main():
threading.Timer(10, giveVelingrad).start()
threading.Timer(15, giveSofia).start()
threading.Timer(25, givePlovdiv).start()



def giveVelingrad():
city = "Velingrad"
response = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="     +city+ "&appid=2e8707d1eb97fbbba33ef766d9ed80ac&units=metric")
weather = response.json()
www = time.strftime("%d.%m.%y %H.%M.%S")
print("\n",www)
print("The weather for ", weather['name'])
print("The temperature is ", weather['main']['temp'])

def giveSofia():
city = "Sofia"
response = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +city+ "&appid=2e8707d1eb97fbbba33ef766d9ed80ac&units=metric")
weather = response.json()
www = time.strftime("%d.%m.%y %H.%M.%S")
print("\n",www)
print("The weather for ", weather['name'])
print("The temperature is ", weather['main']['temp'])

def givePlovdiv():
city = "Plovdiv"
response = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +city+ "&appid=2e8707d1eb97fbbba33ef766d9ed80ac&units=metric")
weather = response.json()
www = time.strftime("%d.%m.%y %H.%M.%S")
print("\n",www)
print("The weather for ", weather['name'])
print("The temperature is ", weather['main']['temp'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```